# Contextual closure type '(_, _) -> _' expects 2 arguments error when using RxSwift Observable.zip

Tags: rx-swift

How to fix following build error when building the code below:

> Contextual closure type '(_, _) -> _' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was
>   used in closure body Insert ',<#arg#> '

**Code**

```
func getIncidentAndResolutionTree() -> Observable<([Incident],[Resolution])>
{
    return Observable.zip(getIncidents(), getResolutionTree(), resultSelector: { results  -> ([Incident], [Resolution]) in
        return results
    })
}
```

**Configuration**

Xcode 9.4.1, Swift 4.1 RxSwift 4.3.1

Comment: What types do `getIncidents()` and `getResolutionTree()` return?

Comment: getIncidents() returns [Incident] and getResolutionTree() returns [Resolution]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda expects 2 parameters, not just `results`.

This will compile -

```swift
return Observable.zip(getIncidents(), getResolutionTree(), resultSelector: { (incidents, resolutions)  -> ([Incident], [Resolution]) in
  return (incidents, resolutions)
})
```

Although it would be more elegant like that -

`return Observable.zip(getIncidents(), getResolutionTree()) { ($0, $1) }`